# Calling an instance method when event occurs

Tags: .net-assembly

This is my situation. I need to subscribe to an event of a type that I am not aware of at compile time. So, I am trying to subscribe dynamically to this type. This is not as simple as creating a delegate of type EventHandler because it is not always of the right type.

So, this is my first dive into the Reflection.Emit namespace, and I need some help. This is what I have so far:

```
private Delegate CreateDynamicClosedDelegate(Type eventHandlerType)
{
    var handler = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, null, GetDelegateParameterTypes(eventHandlerType));

    ILGenerator ilgen = handler.GetILGenerator();

    var onTargetWindowClosedMethodInfo = GetType().GetMethod("OnTargetWindowClosed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // this.OnTargetWindowClosed
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, onTargetWindowClosedMethodInfo);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return handler.CreateDelegate(eventHandlerType);
}
```

As you can see, I am creating a delegate for a specific event type (which is determined at runtime). I think I am almost there, I only need to get the "this." part.

If I understand correctly, ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); should load the instance on the stack. However, since it is a static event handler, I think the first argument is the sender, which is not the instance that contains the method.

In the end, I am trying to produce this code:

```
window.Closed += (sender, e) => this.OnTargetWindowClosed();
```

Subscribing to the event is out of scope (that is easy), but how can I create this method:

```
this.OnTargetWindowClosed();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify the instance on the stack with a DynamicMethod, you have to use an other constructor overload. The owner type is the type of your instance.

```
public DynamicMethod(string name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner);
```

When you create your delegate, you have to use this overload, the target parameter is your instance.

```
public Delegate CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, object target);
```

In your case, it would look like this :

```
private Delegate CreateDynamicClosedDelegate(Type eventHandlerType)
{
    var handler = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, null, GetDelegateParameterTypes(eventHandlerType), this.GetType());

    ILGenerator ilgen = handler.GetILGenerator();

    var onTargetWindowClosedMethodInfo = GetType().GetMethod("OnTargetWindowClosed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // this.OnTargetWindowClosed
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, onTargetWindowClosedMethodInfo);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return handler.CreateDelegate(eventHandlerType, this);
}
```

If you're using silverlight, you can do something like this :

```
public class Dict : Dictionary<int, WindowLogic>
{
    public WindowLogic Get(int key)
    {
        return this[key];
    }
}

public class WindowLogic : IDisposable
{
    static public readonly Dict Instances = new Dict();

    static private int s_increment = 0;

    private int _increment;

    public WindowLogic()
    {
        lock (Instances)
        {
            Instances.Add(_increment = ++s_increment, this);
        }
    }

    private Delegate CreateDynamicClosedDelegate(Type eventHandlerType)
    {
        var handler = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, null, GetDelegateParameterTypes(eventHandlerType));

        ILGenerator ilgen = handler.GetILGenerator();

        var onTargetWindowClosedMethodInfo = GetType().GetMethod("OnTargetWindowClosed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // this.OnTargetWindowClosed
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, typeof(WindowLogic).GetField("Instances", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public));
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, _increment);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Dict).GetMethod("Get"));
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, onTargetWindowClosedMethodInfo);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return handler.CreateDelegate(eventHandlerType);
    }

    public void OnTargetWindowClosed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Type[] GetDelegateParameterTypes(Type eventHandlerType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Instances.Remove(_increment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The issue is that I am using silverlight, and when I use this:

var handler = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, null, GetDelegateParameterTypes(eventHandlerType), this.GetType());

Attempt by security transparent method 'MVVMProviders.Logic.WindowLogic.CreateDynamicClosedDelegate(System.Type)' to access security critical method 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(System.String, System.Type, System.Type[], System.Type)' failed.